# @Named annotation exception

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm getting build exception with `Dagger 2` and `@Named` annotation in `Kotlin` (`Java` working fine with the same code)

`Error:[dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] @javax.inject.Named("LOGGING_INTERCEPTOR") okhttp3.Interceptor cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`

Here is part of my API module code:

```
  @Provides
  @Named(LOGGING_INTERCEPTOR)
  fun provideLoggingInterceptor() = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply { level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }

  @Provides
  @Named(CONNECTIVITY_INTERCEPTOR)
  fun provideConnectivityInterceptor(): Interceptor = ConnectivityInterceptor()

  @Singleton
  @Provides
  fun provideOkHttpClient(
      @Named(CONNECTIVITY_INTERCEPTOR) connectivityInterceptor: Interceptor,
      @Named(LOGGING_INTERCEPTOR) loggingInterceptor: Interceptor
  ): OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .addInterceptor(connectivityInterceptor)
    .apply { if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor) }
    .build()
```

Can somebody explain me why does this happened and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide dependencies as following:

```
@Provides
@Named(LOGGING_INTERCEPTOR)
fun provideLoggingInterceptor(): Interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply { level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }
```

The problem here that you actually provide `HttpLogginInterceptor` not `Interceptor` (for Dagger). You have to specify return type in such case explicitly.

Comment: Can you explain me why?

Comment: And this does not help. Have the same problem

Comment: Thanks, I'm understood my problem by myself )) Didn't see that you write return type